# Pytorch: Loss and Accuracy Curve for BERT

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I am using BERT for a classification problem having `4` classes. I have `10` epochs and `3` batches. I am new to PyTorch and not sure how to code the accuracy and loss curves. Please share any tips or sources for code. I have been stuck trying to figure that out for a while.

I used the following for LSTM:

[image]

Comment: Which accuracy do you want to use to measure your model's performance?

Comment: I just added an image of what I am trying to do. I am trying to apply the same code I did for LSTM Loss and Accuracy curves

Comment: And what's the name of the accuracy being used there?

Comment: It is basically the training and validation accuracy- the know plot to understand the performance of the NN https://towardsdatascience.com/useful-plots-to-diagnose-your-neural-network-521907fa2f45

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you mean. It is the accuracy of the network in classifying the right class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible implementation of top-1 accuracy. Assuming `y_pred` is the output prediction tensor shaped `(batch_size, n_classes)`, here `(3, 4)`. And, `y_true` is the ground-truth dense tensor containing the label class, shaped `(batch_size)`.

```
def accuracy(y_pred, y_true):
    """
    Top-1 accuracy
    Arguments:
      y_pred: is output logits (batch_size=3, n_classes=4)
      y_pred: dense ground-truth (batch_size=3)
    """
    return (y_pred.argmax() == y_true).float().mean()
```

Example usage:

```
>>> y_pred = torch.rand(3, 4)
>>> y_true = torch.randint(0, 4, (3,))
>>> accuracy(y_pred, y_true)
tensor(0.6667)
```